# How can I retrieve image colors using JavaScript and use them as a harmonious background?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am attempting to retrieve the color based on an image using JavaScript, similar to the functionality found in the background section of the TMDB website. In this section, TMDB analyzes the colors of the movie poster and uses them as a background for the page. However, I want to achieve this effect with the poster standing out prominently.

[Example tmdb movie page](https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/502356-the-super-mario-bros-movie)

I have experimented with various methods that I know of, but have not achieved the desired effect.

I expected to retrieve the colors from the image and use them as a background for the section, ensuring that the colors blend harmoniously without any particular element, such as the movie poster, standing out prominently. However, my attempts so far have not yielded the desired result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please read - How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What have you tried? For example, drawing the image on a canvas (assuming there are no CORS issues) enables you to read off the color and alpha channel of any point on the image. Have a go and if still stuck put your code into your question with a description of what isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

This functionality is used when you want to have a preloading for your images.

Now imagine our image is not fully loaded.
How you can use its color palette to set the background?
Thre is no way to do that.

for this perpuse you have to do this from your backend source code. in backend get the color palette and set the background gradient of image.
so you see background gradient of image before loaded.

there is another way which i don't recommend using the **Color thief** library for getting pallete of image and set the background gradient with that.
(the problem is you do this from clinet and until your image loaded, you can't get palette of image and set bg).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).